# Save output of csvwritet to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to convert a .dbf file into a .csv file. When I run my code, the output on the screen is correct but I am not sure how to save it to a csv file. My code is as follows.

```
import sys
import csv
from dbfread import DBF

table = DBF("C:/Users/brownk98/Desktop/result_out.dbf")
writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)

writer.writerow(table.field_names)
for record in table:
    writer.writerow(list(record.values()))
    #writer.save("C:/Users/brownk98/Desktop/result_out.csv")
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please check https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open(r'my_csv_output.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for record in table:
        writer.writerow(list(record.values()))
```

Your 'my_csv_output.csv' file will be in the directory of this python program